# Twitter Application

Tags: android, twitter

Can anyone please tell me what is Message ID and how to retrieve that ID to implement in program for twitter application

Answer (score 0):

Currently the [Twitter API page](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/) is down. Once it is up again, you should be able to find all the information you need ;) You can also follow the [Twitter API tweets](http://twitter.com/twitterapi)